# Replacing values that have duplicates in a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, duplicates

Suppose i have the following table that lists the maker of a unit.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Maker': ['Company1ID', 'SusanID', 'CeramiCorpID', 'PeterID', 'SaraID', 'CeramiCorpID', 'Company1ID']})
print(df)
```

Now consider that i have a much larger table with multiple Person and Corp ID's and i want to reclassify these into two categories, **Person** and **Corporation** has shown in the Expected Column. **ID's are much more complex than what is shown** (eg: f00568ab456b) and are **unique** for Each person or company **but only companies show up in different rows**.

```
| Maker        | Expected |
|--------------|----------|
| Company1ID   | Corp     |
| SusanID      | Person   |
| CeramiCorpID | Corp     |
| PeterID      | Person   |
| SaraID       | Person   |
| CeramiCorpID | Corp     |
| Company1ID   | Corp     |
```

I am basically stuck trying to understand if i need to use either *.apply(lamba x)* or *.replace* with some kind of condition on *.duplicated(keep=False)*. I'm unsure how to go about it either way.

Help appreciated!

Comment: Can you edit your question and put some sample input and expected output?

Comment: Added a table with the code output (maker column) and the expected column showing what i am after.

Comment: So you want to label your column values to find out if it is a cooperation or a person? I do not see what your expected output has to do with duplicate detection.

Comment: I have a huge table with many different ID's that i need to replace with two categories. I thought that the way to go about it is to find if a value has duplicates (indicating that it is a Corporation or a Group and not a single person) IDs are more complex that what is shown here and are unique for people and have duplicates in the case of Corporations or Institutions.

Comment: Problem is sample data are too simplify, please create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not really sure this is what you want, but you could create the 'Expected' column like this:

```
df['Expected'] = ['Corp' if 'Corp' in maker else 'Person' for maker in df['Maker']]
```

**EDIT**:
If you want them to be classified on the amount of occurences:

```
df['Expected'] = ['Corp' if len(df[df['Maker'] == maker]) > 1 else 'Person' for maker in df['Maker']]
```

That would assume that there is no Corp which only occurs once. But if that can be the case then I how do you know if it's a Person or a Corp?

Comment: Unfortunately has i stated in the question the id's are much more complex and some don't contain Corp (ill edit the question to reflect this),

Comment: People have only one occurrence and All Corporations have multiple ocurrences.  That's why I was thinking there could be a solution using. duplicated!